# Tag synonym page to indicate votes missing to be approved

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

It is not fast to know how many votes are missing for a tag synonym to be approved.

I read that they need 4 votes, but inside the tag information.

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag,
>   can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions **will be automatically approved
>   when they reach a score of 4**, and automatically deleted when they
>   reach a score of -2.

What about updating the information in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested to have it like this?

```
 pending (2/4)
```