# Give Tag synonyms their own review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, tag-synonyms, information-display

As per Robert Harvey's suggestion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181956/13295), lets have a review queue for tag synonyms.  It should be filtered so that users will only be shown what they can vote on.  This should help all those languishing tag synonyms.

Comment: But there's so few people in the first place that _can_ vote on the majority of the tag synonyms...

Comment: Exactly, that's why we need to get the word out more to maximize the group that can.

Comment: Related: [Does the Tag Synonym Suggestion System Work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work)

Comment: I see this as rather low priority, as [there's currently only 5 pending suggested synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) (or am I missing something?). I think a more significant issue is that people can't actually request or vote on synonyms as they don't meet the score requirement (there are plenty of outstanding synonym requests on Meta that would've been done already if e.g. 20k users can suggest and vote on synonyms - and most new ones would probably take like an hour to get synonymized).

Comment: @Dukeling, it's a much bigger problem when you hit the __all__ filter on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) __where there are 25 pages of synonym suggestions__.  When you hit the suggested filter, it only shows you what you can vote on.

Comment: Good idea, there should be also a queue for creating tags (so we could lower the rep needed to propose a tag, and increase rep needed to create tag bypassing queue).

Comment: @LanceRoberts Oh ok, though a similar point holds - I can only see 5 (and can't suggest any of those that I see that needs synonymizing), thus a queue won't help me help [so] a whole lot (and many other users probably find themselves in the same situation). And aren't quite a few of those under the `all` filter already approved?

Comment: @Dukeling, yes, I see you're right, the completed ones show also.  I'm not sure how to see all open ones out there.  I just get 3 in my suggested list.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, about your bounty message "_Is it in Stack Exchange development plan?_" I'm pretty sure it needs to first be given the [tag:status-review] tag to go into the development plan. For anyone else reading this, you can read more about [the status-review process here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/997587). (assuming you didn't know about it. If you did just excuse me)

Answer (score 12):

**My thoughts:** (with the goal to minimize development time in mind)

[The suggested synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested) is already a good start.

Personally, I think it's slightly better than a review queue in the sense that you can actually search and sort. Perhaps this functionality should even be extended a bit.

**What needs to change:**

Currently the suggested synonyms page displays all suggested synonyms with tags you've got sufficient score in, even those that *you've already voted on*.

Either:

- Add an option to hide those you've already voted on, or
- Always hide those you've already voted on (why would you want to see them anyway?)

Allow voting directly from that page. Something like this:

[image]

Possibly add a link on [the review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) (to increase visibility - other suggestions welcome).

[image]

Optionally link the review badges to go along with it (???).

But, as there probably aren't too many tag suggestions each of us can vote on, since we need a score of 5 in the tag, I think [the suggestion to allow high-reputation users to be exempt from this requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128874/206447) needs to go in combination with this.

Comment: Voting directly from the page seems like the simplest solution - I had a hard time figuring out exactly where I could vote on the synonyms from the existing page.