# Can we have tag synonym suggestions appear in suggested edit review queues?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, tag-synonyms

So someone suggests a tag synonym. How does anyone else know about it? There is nothing on site which says when a suggestion has been made, so no-one knows. And if they don't know about it it can't be approved.

It would make so much more sense if these suggested synonyms appear in the suggested edits review queue. After all, tag wiki edits appear there.

Can this be done?

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense for them to appear there - they aren't suggested edits or anywhere near the same thing. Tag wiki edits appear there because tag wikis are just another type of post and use pretty much the exact same mechanisms as questions and answers. Modifying the queue to handle suggested tag synonyms would be infinity more difficult than just [creating a separate queue for them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202754/give-tag-synonyms-their-own-review-queue).

Comment: @animuson well that seems like a better idea. But that was asked 3 years ago, and nothing has happened to fix this problem?