# Migrated questions don't have a user action label in the question list

Tags: bug, migrated-questions, question-lists

The active tab on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) just showed this:

[image]

Normally I can see what caused that question to popup in the active list. But for migrated questions a friendly text is missing. I could only find out by [visiting that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304152/some-kind-of-notification-system-for-when-tag-synonyms-are-suggested).

Is the default behavior for migrated posts to show no label for the user action? It kind of would make sense as migration is not a single user action. For UX consistency I would prefer the label *migrated* for those cases.

User [Alex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/390967/alex) found another similar glitch on April, 5th 2020 when a question is [migrated from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/343939/revisions) to a child-meta, in this case [IPS.SE meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3966/timeline). The active list on IPS Meta shows:

> [image: active list entry]

Notice that both action and user are missing here. The user did have an account on the migration date on both sites, so that is not the root cause

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Hooray. I'm on TV!

Comment: Now also reported on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368294/578411