# Unused meta tags that still persist

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, per-site-meta, localization

I found that some meta sites have tags that actually have not been used for a long time and are not deleted yet. Looks like these are some sort of "special" potential popular tags for English-speaking people.

But I see no reason why they should exist on every meta. For instance, why does ["voting"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voting) exist on ruSO.meta, or ["bounty"](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty) on Russian Language Stack Exchange? And so on.

Can we just burninate such tags? Who is responsible for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are [default-tags](/questions/tagged/default-tags) ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233922/295232) is a list of them). On new Meta sites, it may take a (long) while before an appropriate question is asked, therefore I *presume* the tag pruning script ignores those default tags.

IMHO, you shouldn't burninate them, but instead synonymize them with their localized counterparts. This is what happened e.g. on Spanish Language Meta, where [[tags] was synonymized with [etiquetas]](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/etiquetas/synonyms).

Comment: Synonymize is not a good/relevant option for non-Latin languages like Russian. It can be relevant on main site (ruSO) since many technologies came from US, Europe, but I'm not sure about ruSO.meta or rusSE entirely. The probability of using 'voting' on ru metas is extremely low. Using them as a synonym looks just as a easiest workaround, better option - just let the community to delete them.

Comment: That requires dev work for something which is IMHO trivial, while synonymizing can be done by the community / moderators.

Comment: Synonymization engine [should be improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202754/339911) cause for community itself is hard to synonymize. And moderators on RuSO.meta have very weak participation. I think we need more, i.e. I'm waiting for the nearest election at least.

Comment: It's also worth noting that having synonyms from the English terms helps staff (at least, those staff who might not necessarily know the language as well) find the relevant corresponding tags to use when posting something on non-English meta sites. Usually, we can ask a staff member who is fluent in the language if needed, but it just saves some time if we don't have to :)